# Get localized name of day with Twig Intl Extension

Tags: php, symfony, date, localization, twig

Using the Twig Intl Extension in a symfony project gives you the Twig Filter `localizeddate`.

You can even choose from some "presets" like `{{ date|localizeddate('full', 'medium') }}` to print out a value (german locale) like: **Montag, 24. August 2015 um 23:00:00**

But how can I just output the **name of the day**?

*Note: `{{ date.format('D') }}` will output the name of the day in the english language, not the current locale set in symfony / twig environment.*

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
{{ date|localizeddate('full', 'none', app.request.locale, null, 'EEE') }}
```

Read the docs for the function [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/blob/master/doc/intl.rst).

Comment: {{ date|localizeddate('full', 'none', app.request.locale, null, 'EEEE') }} for full  name

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

`{{ date.format('D')|trans }}`

Comment: Thanks, Emmanuel. I would call it a workaround, and I didn't even think about just translating via the translator component. I will solve the problem this way now, but I am still looking for a way using the Intl extension, which made for that kind of problems in my opinion.