# Can someone explain the localizeddate() signature to me?

Tags: twig

I'm currently working on a somewhat old project symfony project. So old, it needs to use "twig/extension" instead of "twig/extra-bundle".

I found the answer to the blocking problem already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059802/get-localized-name-of-day-with-twig-intl-extension), but the top comment (which does the trick) does not contain an explanation.

Comment: https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get localized name of day with Twig Intl Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059802/get-localized-name-of-day-with-twig-intl-extension)